# Save Highchart directly to specific path

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to save the PDF which is getting downloaded from Highchart Export module to a specific path by default?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Highcharts from a web browser there is no way to tell the browser where to download an incoming file. The file goes to the configured download folder. There are however browser extensions that can change that behavior like for example [this one for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/).

Comment: to add a point, is there any possibility where i can configure the required path is the js file(exporting.js)

Comment: No, this is outside of Highcharts/exporting.js territory. File downloads happen on the HTTP level and there is no provision in HTTP to specify where a download should be saved on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Default exporting tool doens't support it, but you can configure / customise your own [exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server).